# How do I dispose of a corpse?

Tags: fallout-4

So I killed a bunch of raiders from a settlement, now their rotting fly infested corpses are lying around clogging up the joint.  How do I dispose of their corpses?

Comment: I'm curious too. I have a couple of houses that are infested with radroach and bloatfly corpses and no way to get rid of them. I know my settlers don't mind the abysmal sanitary issues as long as they don't have to drink irradiated water, but I'd rather not have my son live in that kind of place once I bring him back home.

Comment: To me, the most anoying part is that I once spent 10 minutes dragging Feral Ghoul corpses out of one of my settlements... and then the next time I travelled back they were all over the place again.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## Use the console

As with previous Bethesday games, the `markfordelete` or `disable`  console commands can be used to force an entity to despawn. Using `markfordelete` may be safer as there are some indications that using `disable` will not remove the object from the world state in your savegame. The former is also less likely to bug out as it should follow the default cleanup behaviour.

Via [the Wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_4_console_commands):

> **markfordelete** - Similar to disable, will delete any item from the game, removing it permanently. It may disappear immediately, or it may require you to exit and re-enter the area.

While I haven't confirmed this myself, using the console [apparently does not disable achievements.](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/164594-fallout-4/72798315)

Comment: (This has the added benefit of being usable from every piece of a corpse as they should all remain part of a single entity.)

Comment: Its worth noting that markfordeletion is likely safer where the risk of buggs is concerned.

Comment: Creation/Gamebryo Engine : How do I do "X" ? : USE THE CONSOLE.

Answer (score 9):

if you have running water nearby you can drag the corpse there and watch it float away

Answer (score 8):

Build a small shack and drag all bodies there?

=Build a graveyard.

Comment: That doesn't really get rid of them completely though  AndI've already dragged them to my crops as fertilizer for now :P

Comment: How exactly do you drag things (or corpses) in Fallout 4, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: @Nolonar just hold the 'e' button while interacting with something

Comment: Also i have to mention I tend to gib things a lot with head shots, and having to drag individual eyeballs is a huge PITA

Comment: Hey, you may end up with cannibalistic plants like those in the garden in Arroyo :) Maybe eating corpses with cannibal perk removes them?

Comment: @z' You dragged the giblets? I find dragging the body alone to be tedious enough.

Answer (score 4):

Chances are it is not despawning because you are visiting the "cell" or loaded area, frequently.
Travel far away from the settlement in question, and do not go back for about 10-15 in-game days (you can sleep/wait it off if you wish)  that will "reset" the cell which will remove any temporary mobs.  That should fix your problem. If you go back to the settlement too early, this 10-15 day timer will reset.

if you do not wish to do that then use Disable in-console.  Do NOT use markfordelete.

Most of the creatures that spawn are Randomly generated.  If you use markfordelete, it will delete that creature and any spawns like it afterwards.

EX.
5 Raiders attack a settlement.  I kill them.  I use markfordelete on one of them.  there is a good chance that if raiders attack again, there will only be 4 raiders.  This is what happened with skyrim so I cannot imagine it being any different.
On top of that markfordelete is permanent, so you can't fix mistakes.

Yes, disable doesnt "remove" the mob from the game, but it unloads it from memory, and prevents FO4 from loading it again,  so while it may slow down load times, it will not affect fps or anything else in-game.  It is just a much more safer option to choose.

Comment: In Skyrim, if you use markfordelete on a dragon corpse, for example, it will not delete every other dragon afterwards. And since fallout 4 uses the creation engine too, I think this answer is wrong.

Comment: I'm with @YUNOWORK - I've used markfordelete many a time in Fallout 4 and haven't seen this effect in play as you describe it. You're gonna need to back this claim up with a reference or a video proving this.

Comment: I don't think the 'cell' theory works everywhere. When I first went through Red Rocket Truck Stop I killed a bunch of mole rats. Red Rocket is someplace you'll go through very frequently in early games, but their corpse despawned in a few in-game days after I finished the Freedom Museum quest.

Answer (score 3):

It's not ideal but it saves using console commands but you could "bin" all the corpses. 
I have erected 4 walls and a staircase leading up. you can dump them inside.
It gets them out of the way

Answer (score 2):

I have a batch file which I run every start. One of the lines is:

```
setgs iHoursToClearCorpses 2
```

As ThreeTen suggested, go away from the cell for a while.

If you use `MarkForDelete`, try using `Disable` first, in case you've selected the wrong item (like Dogmeat!). You can then `MarkForDelete` once you're sure you have the intended target.

Answer (score 1):

There is a mod that can help you get rid of corpses in your settlements. 

(and it gives you materials for the bodies!)

[**Scrap dead things**](http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/6497/?)

I do not personally use this mod, so I can not account for how well it works.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same trouble until i noticed that only corpses with items in them were lingering around my settlements. Try looting all the items inside the corpses. It should allow them to dissapear.

Answer (score -1):

I just blew them away with missiles