# How to get rid of the dead creatures in skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

I can't figure out how to get rid of the dead bodies. I reload and everything and they stay there. How to get rid of them?

Comment: [Dead bodies everywhere!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0eCQ9F1OPvs)

Comment: Is there a Serial Killers Stack Exchange?  That's the best place to ask how to get rid of a body...

Comment: This was previously asked for Fallout 4 (same engine) [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/242857/how-do-i-dispose-of-a-corpse) but this is potentially a duplicate of "*[How do I get rid of corpses?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/185049/how-do-i-get-rid-of-corpses)*", though that OP was on the PC version.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman no, and I don't want to have a website called that!

Comment: @JimJones - Says the person who shares a username with a cult-leader responsible for hundreds of deaths in the 70's...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman lol

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sometimes Skyrim doesn't delete dead bodies (or it takes an unreasonable amount of time). I for one had a dead troll at Whiterun's Gate that I didn't even kill and he stayed there for almost a whole game month.

If you are playing on PC, you can use the console to manually delete the corpses. To do that you have to enter in the console, and click on the corpse you want to delete. Then

> **markfordelete** - Which marks the target to be deleted upon the next load
>
> **disable** - Which removes the character from vision (but it still loads it, you just cannot see it. But if you `markfordelete` first, the target will then be invisible and then deleted.

---

Alternatively you can use mods to similar effects. There are a few mods at [nexusmods.com](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/?) which is generally a reputable source for several mods of different games. However, you should always scan every file for safety purposes.

Comment: Alright thanks! Im on xbox 360 right now so i cant do that

Comment: @Benjaminward I'm sorry, there's nothing you can do but hope the game eventually deletes it.

Comment: @Benjaminward can wait for a while to actively encourage the game to delete it.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are on Xbox, the easiest way is to rest a long time and reset that map area.

Here are the steps:

- go to a far away place
- rest for 30 days straight

You're going to a far away place so the map you want to reset is no longer in use, and the 30 days is to reset it.

Answer (score 1):

Dead bodies usually despawn after a while. There were some bodies in river wood and after a while when I went back they had despawned so no worries. Just wait a little bit. If it really bothers you, you can just drag the bodies away somewhere where you won't see them. (To drag bodies or pick up object without moving them into your inventory hold the A button where it says search)